# Show contents of two merged directory listings

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsscrollview

I would like to merge the two directories listings (already done and works they show up in NSTableView), but also display the contents of the files in an NSScrollview, now the problem lies in iterating through the list, and I couldn't figure out how I would come about that problem, I tried different techniques.

For now I get: "-[NSTextView replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: nil NSString given.", probably because the iteration code is incorrect...

```
NSInteger row = [logsTableView selectedRow];

NSString *path1 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Logs/"];
NSString *path2 = @"/Library/Logs/";

NSArray *directoryList1 = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path1 error:nil]
                           pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"log", nil]];

NSArray *directoryList2 = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path2 error:nil]
                           pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"log", nil]];

NSMutableArray *directoryList = [NSMutableArray array];
[directoryList addObjectsFromArray:directoryList1];
[directoryList addObjectsFromArray:directoryList2];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < directoryList.count; i++)
{        
    if (row == i)
    {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < directoryList1.count; i++)
        {
            NSString *filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"Library/Logs/%@", [directoryList objectAtIndex:i]];

            NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                         error:NULL];

            [logsScrollViewTextView setString:content];
        }
        for (NSUInteger i = directoryList.count - directoryList1.count; i < directoryList.count; i++)
        {
            NSString *filePath = @[@"/Library/Logs/%@", [directoryList objectAtIndex:i]];

            NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                             error:NULL];

            [logsScrollViewTextView setString:content];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why iterate at all? You have the row which is the index into the array... All you need to know is row >= list1 count.

Comment: Thanks @Wain again for your quick reply. It's because as it is now, it shows the listings so to say in an order, directoryList1 first then directoryList2 plus they come from different directories. The problem lies in the fact that they are in different locations, so to display the contents of each file I would have to iterate twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate. All you need to do is to check which array the file name came from.

Assuming you aren't sorting the list, this is `if (row >= directoryList1.count)`. This check tells you which list it came from so you can set the prefix.

If you are sorting and the names are unique you could use `[directoryList1 containsObject:...)`.

Comment: Thanks @Wain I replaced all the iterations including the `row == i` loop with your if statements, but still I get `-[NSTextView replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: nil NSString given.` I used `if (row <= directoryList1.count)` and `if (row >= directoryList1.count)` respectively. Also `row` instead of `i` And the array is not sorted.

Comment: You don't need 2 ifs, just an if else. >= means it's the second list. If you use < don't make it <= (or it will be wrong for the last item). Add logging to see what the values are. Use the file manager to check the file exists. You may need to use ~ and expand...

Comment: OK its now one if clause, also only one `= sign` used and logging reveals row is `(null)`. The NSTableView shows the list correctly, but not scrollable. And it crashes on selecting a row, again `nil string given`.

Comment: So you need to find the selected row number first if that isn't currently set properly.

Comment: I figured some things out, it works perfectly in the directoryList1, because the code should include a `/` in front of path, but the directoryList2 still crashes, because of `NSArrayI getFileSystemRepresentation:maxLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. Also on that line I get the following compiler warning `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString *_strong' with an expression of type 'NSArray *'`.

Comment: Need the stack trace. Probably shouldn't use stringByAppendingFormat, there is a method for appending path components.

Comment: Ok, so you can't assign an array to a string and call a string method on it... Edit the question to add your current code.

Comment: The thing is, the line seems to read correct: `NSString *filePath = @[@"/Library/Logs/%@", [directoryList objectAtIndex:selectedRow]];`

Comment: You have `@[` at the start of the line, that is a literal array definition.

Comment: Take a look at `filePosixPermissions` (Dictionary method) from the file manager.

Comment: Question is extremely fully answered, I will open another question then for this problem if I can't fix it myself. Thanks so much @Wain again!!!